# convergence of a subsequence of function for a given rational in a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n : [ a , b ] \longrightarrow R$ satisfy $\mid f_n(x) \mid \leq 1$ for all $x$ and $n$ . Show that there is a subsequence $(f_{nk} )$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f_{nk}$ exists for each rational $x$ in $[ a , b ]$. Use a diagonalization argument.

I suppose I am to use the fact that the rationals are countable in the given closed interval. I also have in mind the tabular analogy where $f_n$ are the row ids ( thus it goes to infinity) and the rationals are the columns (countable number of them)but finding it difficult to get that subsequence such that the given limit exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate rationals $\{q_j\}_j \subset [a,b]$. Start with $q_1$. Since $|f_n(q_1)| \le 1$ you can find subsequence $\{n_k^{(1)}\}$ such that $f_{n_k^{(1)}}(q_1) \to v_1$, where $v_1 \in [-1,1]$ is some number (we used the fact that from bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^d$ we can extract converging subsequence (Bolzano - Weierstrass)). Now, from $\{n_k^{(1)}\}$ by the same reasoning we can extract subsequence $\{n_k^{(2)}\}$ such that $f_{n_k^{(2)}}(q_2) \to v_2 \in [-1,1]$. Repeat the same for every rational $q_j$ and finally take $n_k = n_k^{(k)}$. Since for any $j \in \mathbb N_+$ it's a subsequence (starting from index $k \ge j$) of $n_k^{(j)}$ we get $f_{n_k}(q_j) \to v_j$ for any $j \in \mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @Dominik_Kutek thank you for the insight! I could see it now.